# Error With Very Simple Implementation Of List Max Using Fold

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to implement `max'`

```
max' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
```

using `foldl` (Sadly, [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) doesn't seem to have exercises, so I'm making them up).

So, I can write a lambda taking two integers and returning the maximum:

```
(\x y -> if x > y then x else y) 2 3
```

and I can `foldl` a list using it:

```
foldl (\x y -> if x > y then x else y) 2 [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

So I assumed that what I need is:

```
max' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
max' xs = foldl (\x y -> if x > y then x else y) (head xs) (tail xs)
```

But the above lines fails with:

```
    Use foldl1
Found:

foldl (\ x y -> if x > y then x else y) (head xs) (tail xs)
Why Not:

foldl1 (\ x y -> if x > y then x else y) xs
```

I'd like to ask:

1. What is the problem in this case?
2. How can I figure out future errors from messages of this type?

Comment: It's not an error, it's an hlint suggestion saying "your implementation is totally fine, while it may be improved by blah blah".

Comment: @zakyggaps Ahhh, that makes so much sense, now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note you're reimplementing `maximum` not max, which you can use as well

```
foldl max (head xs) (tail xs)


Prelude> :info max
class Eq a => Ord a where
  ...
  max :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'

Prelude> :info maximum
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a    -- Defined in `Data.List'
```

Comment: Thanks, though I was aware of this function. It was just for self improvement.

Comment: Or, we could combine the compiler suggestion and this answer, yielding `maximum' = foldl1 max`.